# Javascript CR+LF will break string?

Tags: javascript

When storing '\n\r' inside a string constant it will make the Javascript engine throw an error like "unterminated string" and so on.

How to solve this?

More info: basically I want to use Javascript to select text into a TEXTAREA HTML field and insert newlines. When trying to stuff those constants, I get an error.

Comment: I think on old macs it was actually \n\r as opposed to windows \r\n - on all *nix platforms it is just \n (new-line as oppesed to \r\n or \n\r where the \n is line-feed). The order doesn't matter anyways, it is a relic from old ibm typewrites - \r is carriage return and told the typewriter head to move back to the starting position while \n told it to scroll the physical paper a line up

Comment: Here's the code: `var mystring = '\r\n<p>';` traps an error.

Answer (score 9):

[String literals](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-7.8.4) must not contain plain line break characters like CR and LF:

> A '[*LineTerminator*](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-7.3)' character cannot appear in a string literal, even if preceded by a backslash `\`. The correct way to cause a line terminator character to be part of the string value of a string literal is to use an escape sequence such as `\n` or `\u000A`.

So having a line break like this is invalid:

```
"foo
bar"
```

Instead you need to use an escape sequence like:

```
"foo\nbar"
```

Comment: Are you sure that’s what causes the error? Did you try [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/) as another validator?

Comment: I'm using firebug, however also JSLint throws an error: `Problem at line 81 character 15: Unclosed string.` and `Problem at line 81 character 15: Stopping, unable to continue.`